# removing item from Flatlist

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I need to make a function to remove items from a Flatlist, this below is the one I'm using, but instead of deleting the item, it adds the same one again:

```
removeItem = (key) => {
    let filteredItems = this.state.workoutList.filter(item => item.key !== key);
    this.setState({ workoutList: filteredItems })
  }
```

and this what shows in the Terminal when I run it:

```
Array [
  Object {
    "Friday": false,
    "Monday": true,
    "Saturday": false,
    "Sunday": false,
    "Thursday": false,
    "Tuesday": false,
    "Wednesday": false,
    "key": 0.3257222928276463,
    "workoutName": "",
  },
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you cannot change a state variable directly,  you need to use `Object.assign()` to make a copy of this array from state to manipulate it.

```
removeItem = (key) => {
   let filteredItems = Object.assign([], this.state.workoutList).filter(item => item.key !== key);
   this.setState({ workoutList: filteredItems })
}
```

should do the job

Comment: thanks for your response, but it didn't fix the problem, it still creates again the same object and returns the warning: ` Encountered two children with the same key, `0.2881646929937661`.`

Comment: The state variable isn't being changed, using `filter` on `this.state.workoutList` doesn't mutate the array